# Mysql: Getting all days of a month

Tags: mysql

Need suggestion for a query.One solution is create a days table for all months.

I am trying to get `count(c3.id)` for all days of month `February`.
As in `cs.created_at`, some dates are missing, how can I use below clause.

```
group by day(cs.created_at)
```

something like `group by day(month(cs.created_at))` not working..

```
 select count(case when cs.id IN(select max(id) from complaint3_status
                                  where complaint_id=c3.id  and status_type=10)
                        and cs.status_value=11 then c3.id end
             ) as resolved_complaints 
 from  complaint3 c3, complaint3_status cs, 
       company c, complaint3_details cd, user3 u3 
 where c3.id=cs.complaint_id 
   and cd.complaint_id=c3.id 
   and u3.id=c3.user_id 
   and c.id=c3.company_id 
   and c3.company_id=852 
   and month(cs.created_at)=02 
   and year(cs.created_at)=2014 
 group by day(cs.created_at)
```

Comment: As you already filtering results by `year` and `month`, I don't think there is a necessity to group again on `day` of a date. Instead you can try `group by cs.created_at` directly.

Comment: yeah..gives same result but i am trying to get all days of a month as cs.created_at not contains some dates

Comment: Just to clarify: You are trying to have one row per day, but sometimes you have no data for a day. You want that row to be shown just with zeroes in the other columns. Correct?

Comment: IMO: Create the days table that you mentioned in the first sentence, then LEFT JOIN from that table to the results above. (Also, I would suggest change the above query to use ANSI JOIN's, not the theta (i.e., comma style, implicit) that you are currently using)

Comment: yeah..basically i am looking for some other option if possible..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..I will surely follow it..

Comment: Can we add certain condition in group by clause..suppose by querying i am getting 10 users from source 1,20 users from source 2,3 from source 3 and 12 from source 4.I am trying to get result from 2 sources only source 1 contains(1+2+3) users i.e 33 users and source 4 12 users

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the day(cs.created_at) in the select statement.

```
 select day(cs.created_at),count(case when cs.id IN(select max(id) from complaint3_status where complaint_id=c3.id  and status_type=10) and
  cs.status_value=11   then c3.id end) as resolved_complaints 
  from  complaint3 c3 , complaint3_status cs, 
  company c,complaint3_details cd,user3 u3 where c3.id=cs.complaint_id and cd.complaint_id=c3.id and
   u3.id=c3.user_id and c.id=c3.company_id and c3.company_id=852 and month(cs.created_at)=02 and year(cs.created_at)=2014 group by day(cs.created_at)
```